# Get subparser by name

Tags: python, argparse

I have multiple subparsers, and I'd like to use use `parser.error` to show errors.

```
main_parser   = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers    = main_parser.add_subparsers(dest = 'subparser_name')  

password_subparser = subparsers.add_parser('password')
password_subparser.add_argument('--username',
        default = None, required = False,
        dest = "username", help='Target username')

web_subparser = subparsers.add_parser('web')
web_subparser.add_argument('--port',
        default = 8765, required = False, type = int,
        dest = "port", help='Listening port')

args = main_parser.parse_args()
```

Usually I can use `main_parser.error`, but to make the error more precisely, I should use the current subparser, e.g `password_subparser`

Now I know the name of the current subparser, aka `args.subparser_name`

But I can't locate `password_subparser` from `main_parser`, any ideas?

There's no method like, `main_parser.get_subparser(subparser_name)`

Comment: Do you need to? You get the reference like this `password_subparser = main_parser.add_subparsers(dest = 'subparser_name')  ` and use it as normal.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have 10 subparsers, I can identify which subparser is in use, but only the name

Comment: where do you define ``password_subparser``?

Comment: @daisy: if you want to get the objects themselves, store the somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not documented anywhere, it appears that you can access the subparsers through the `subparsers.choices` dictionary:

```
>>> subparsers.choices['password']
ArgumentParser(prog='untitled.py password', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)
```

Comment: If you don't like using an undocumented feature, you could easily build the equivalent dictionary when creating the `parser`.  `mydict['password']=password_subparser`, etc.  Better yet write a utility function to do that for you.